# Getting a certain letter from a value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Is there a way to get a certain letter from a value inside of an array?

For example, if my array is:

```
const names = ['john', 'james']
```

Is there a way to get the 2nd letter in 'john' using code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the subscript operator (`[]`) to get a specific element of the array. Then, you can use the subscript operator again to get a specific character from a string:

```
const result = names[0][1];
```

Note that both array indexes and string indexes are zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var names = ["John", "james", "jacky", "man"];
  var result = names[0][1];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use the `substring` function.

```js
const names = ['john', 'james'];

//substr(<where to start>, <length of string>)
var letter = names[0].substr(1, 1);
```